# R : Convert object of type closure (= function) to string, inside a function

Tags: r

If I want to get the name of a function (as a string) I can do this:

```r
as.character(quote(mean))
#> [1] "mean"
```

Or this:

```r
as.character(substitute(mean))
#> [1] "mean"
```

However this doesn't work if I try to get the function name inside another function.

e.g.

```r
print_fun <- function (fun) {
  function_name <- as.character(quote(fun))
  print(function_name)
}
  print_fun(mean)
#> [1] "fun"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to substitute `quote` by `substitute`.

```
print_fun <- function (fun) {
  function_name <- as.character(substitute(fun))
  print(function_name)
}
print_fun(mean)

#> [1] "mean"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was stupid not to try that out I guess. This is what stress does to you.

Comment: Thanks, I just learned a bit more about how stackoverflow works :)